# Change Font-Weight of textbox onfocus by javascript in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a textbox if the text is empty is will show "Add Email" in red& bold.
    
       
       
        Email
       
       
        
         '              onfocus="txtEmailOnfocus(this)">

```
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>  

TextBox txtEmail = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEmail");
            if (txtEmail.Text == "")
            {
                txtEmail.Text = "Add Email";

                txtEmail.Attributes.Add("Style", "font-weight:bold;color:#ff0000 ");
             }
```

And I want to change the font-weight to normal but it doesn't work.

```
function txtEmailOnfocus(txt) {
        if (txt.value.toLowerCase() == 'add email') txt.value = '';
        txt.style.color = "#444444";
        txt.style.font-weight="normal";

       }
```

Thanks a lot.

Bob

Change Font-Weight of textbox onfocus by javascript in ASP.Net

Comment: try *txt.style.fontWeight*

Comment: Alternatively, you could toggle a CSS class on the element, and set all the styling properties there - removing the presentation from the control logic.